# How can I download file from ftp server with golang

Tags: go, ftp

Can't find a way to download file from ftp with golang.

Tried jlaffaye/ftp library - is connecting to server, can make, delete, folders and files, but doesn't download. Don't show error either.

```
c, err := ftp.Dial("ftp.example.org:21", ftp.DialWithTimeout(5*time.Second))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

err = c.Login(ftpUsername, ftpPassword)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

c.ChangeDir("desiredDir")

_, err = c.Retr("desiredFile.zip")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
} else {
    println("ok")
}

if err := c.Quit(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Desired result is to download file
Compiler doesn't show any error message

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code you are skipping `*Response` handling (which is ReadCloser). You can save it to the local file.

```
// ...

res, err := c.Retr("desiredFile.zip")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

defer res.Close()

outFile, err := os.Create("desiredFile.zip")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

defer outFile.Close()

_, err = io.Copy(outFile, res)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```